# Automatically give permissions to user in Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-devops

I have created visual studio online site using azure and backed by our company active directory.
And when going to user management site (example image, not my screenshot) in the search box I can see all the users from the active directory which means that I'm properly connected (I guess).

[image: user management]

And here is the problem which I wasn't able to solve.
I would like to know if it is possible to automatically give read permissions to users from active directory that try to access the site.
Currently they can login, but when they access the site it says that they don't have permissions and I have to manually add them one by one and I don't want to do that.

Do I maybe need some special active directory group that I add there as a user or what? I'm not active directory admin so I don't have access to its settings.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: How many people per day are you actually hiring?

Comment: Our team has only 6 people, but the company is big and I can never know who might try to access the site to check the status of some tests or something else in our vso so I can't bother with setting the permissions individually. Everyone should at least have read access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently VSO does not support AD groups. In addition, just because you assign a licence, does not mean that they should have permission to everything. You my be a special case, but the choice of access should be left to the Team Project owners.

Comment: Do you maybe know when is the expected date when this feature might be supported. I'm a team project owner so it's not a problem adding permissions there.  
Only thing that I really want is automatic assignment of licenses. And I would be completely satisfied when someone from the domain logs in for the first time gets a stakeholder license.

Comment: Not sure.. Have you checked the feature list on visualstudio.com?